# Confidence intervals for integer parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, discrete-distributions

I'm interested, purely out of curiosity, in what methods can be used to calculate confidence intervals for discrete integer model parameters.

As an example, consider the model (which I can flesh out with code if needs be)

$$
y \in [0,1]; \\
P(y_i = 1) = 
\begin{cases}
.25 \text{ if } i \lt \theta \\
.75 \text{ otherwise };
\end{cases} \\
i \in [1, 2, \dots, n];\\
\theta \in [1, 2, \dots, n];\\
$$

where the change point $\theta$ is an integer parameter.

I can think of a few approaches one could take here:

- Bootstrapping
- Using Bayesian methods, with a Uniform prior, to sample from the posterior $P(\theta | Y) \propto P(Y | \theta)$, and then treat the percentiles as bounds of the corresponding confidence interval. I think this is appropriate, given that for many models credible intervals with uniform priors are equivalent to frequentist confidence intervals.
- Treat $\theta$ as a continuous variable...

  - ...and use Fisher information to calculate standard errors. This won't work here because $P(Y | \theta)$ is a step function.
  - For other models, it may be possible to calculate continuous (decimal) standard errors (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/374961/42952)). I guess the resulting confidence interval, $\hat \theta \pm 1.96 \times SE$ could be rounded off to integer values.

So, what methods are available for calculating confidence intervals for integer parameters, either for models of this form or in general?

> [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8844/42952) question might also be relevant.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126148/generalization-of-fisher-information-for-a-discrete-parameter

Comment: You can calculate a likelihood interval : $\{\theta: \log\mathcal L(\theta) \ge \log\mathcal L_{max}-c\}$ which is similar to the Bayesian method. Of course this does not guarantee exact coverage, but neither do the other methods.